# Python function throwing invalid syntax error

Tags: python-2.7, pickle

I have a function to unpickle some spectrometer data, reproduced in extreme brevity here:

```
def loader(filename): 
     global lister
     lister = pd.read_pickle(str(filename) + ".pkl")
```

The function works as I'd like it to, except that I'd rather just tab/complete the filename than have to backspace over the file extension. I am uncertain why I can't just throw the filename (20160321.pkl) into the function itself.  I can make strings that appear as '20160321.pkl', but why can't I make strings of the tab-completed filename containing the extension, as in the following?

```
    def loader(filename): 
         global lister
         lister = pd.read_pickle(str(filename))
```

I'm sure there's a simple reason for this that I haven't yet learned.

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: usually in an interpreter:  

loader(20160321) works, as I add the .pkl later.  


loader(20160321.pkl) does not work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - are you calling it with `loader("20160321")`? Is your question how to calculate / put together the filename automatically without having to pass the date string yourself?

Comment: Not quite. With the function defined as my first code block, I call `loader(20160321)` and everything functions properly. I would rather call `loader(20160321.pkl)`, as in the second code block; however, this throws a syntax error.

Comment: Ah I see what's happening - I've clarified how to pass in the filename as you want in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're calling `loader(20160321)` you're actually passing in an integer (`20160321`), not a string. This is why the first approach works because `str(filename)` converts that integer into a string and then it adds `".pkl"` at the end.

When you're calling `loader(20160321.pkl)` you're getting a syntax error because a number can have a decimal point in it but not with characters after that (so `3.5` is allowed but `3.abc` is not allowed).

If you want to call it with the extension then you need to pass in a string: `loader("20160321.pkl")`. You can also use single quotes (`loader('20160321.pkl')`) but in any case you're looking to pass in a string.

Comment: I figured it would be this simple.  I was hoping to save a few keystrokes, but it looks like either way will be equivalent. Thank you; I will accept your answer.